# Как генерировать wpnonce?

Tags: wordpress

Создаю плагин. Мне надо по Ajax получить записи из базы данных и отрисовать таблицу с  записями где будут ссылки на редактирование и удаление записи.
С редактированием все получилось, а с удалением требуется создать wpnonce и тут начались танцы с бубном.
Мне нужна ссылка типа

> http://localhost/photorent6/wp-admin/post.php?post=7470&action=trash&_wpnonce=78f5bdd38a

Если я использую такой код:

```
$url = admin_url("post.php?post=".$inventories[$i][0]); 
$complete_url = wp_nonce_url( $url, 'trash');
```

то генерируется URL

> http://localhost/photorent6/wp-admin/post.php?post=7470&_wpnonce=e0bf776d90

то есть "action=trash" не добавляется, и значения _wpnonce одинаковые, не уникальные.

А если я использую другой вариант:

```
$url = admin_url("post.php?post=".$inventories[$i][0]);
$my_nonce = wp_create_nonce($inventories[$i][0]);// ID записи
$adm_url = $url."&action=trash"."&_wpnonce=".$my_nonce;
```

То генерируется URL правильный, с уникальными wpnonce, но при попытке удалить запись получаю сообщение что "Срок действия ссылки за которой Вы перешли, закончился"

Как правильно генерировать wpnonce ?

Comment: извинитеянезнаю почемутут все поехало

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html